# Error definiendo los offset en mpu6050

Tags: arduino

tengo un problema, estoy usando el MPU6050, obtuve la calibracion de offsets mediante un codigo que encontre en internet, al principio con los ejemplos fue facil usar los offsets el problema fue cuon este codigo:

```
#include <MPU6050.h>
#include<Wire.h>

MPU6050 sensor;  // I2C address of the MPU-6050
const int MPU = 0x68;
int16_t AcX,AcY,AcZ,Tmp,GyX,GyY,GyZ;
 
// value returned is in interval [-32768, 32767] so for normalize multiply GyX and others for gyro_normalizer_factor
// float gyro_normalizer_factor = 1.0f / 32768.0f;


 
void setup(){
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);
  Wire.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
 
 
void loop(){
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);

  Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU,14,true);  // request a total of 14 registers

  sensor.setXAccelOffset(90);
    
  AcX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)    
  AcY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
  AcZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)
  Tmp=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x41 (TEMP_OUT_H) & 0x42 (TEMP_OUT_L)
  GyX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) & 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
  GyY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) & 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
  GyZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x47 (GYRO_ZOUT_H) & 0x48 (GYRO_ZOUT_L)
 

  Serial.print(AcX); Serial.print(";"); Serial.print(AcY); Serial.print(";"); Serial.print(AcZ); Serial.print(";");
  Serial.print(GyX); Serial.print(";"); Serial.print(GyY); Serial.print(";"); Serial.print(GyZ); Serial.println("");
  Serial.flush();
 
  delay(25);
}
```

Al momento de definir el offset me manda en todos los ejes un -1, pero si no defino el offset me manda valores no calibrados, alguien tiene idea de porque me manda valores de "1" en lugar de los valores corrctos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hace unos días me encontraba con el mismo problema, creí que era la conexión con mi Arduino o el mismo módulo, investigando un poco más, encontré que la librería no tiene buen rendimiento por lo que no te recomiendo usarla, por lo contrario, te muestro el codigo que me funciono sin problemas.

```
/*
  Código de WEB https://www.proyecto-teos.com
*/

#include <Wire.h>

const int signalPathRT = 0x68;

const float accelerationRT = 16384.0;
const float turnRT = 131.0;
int16_t acXT, acYT, acZT, gyXT, gyYT, gyZT;
float differentialT;

float accelerationArrayT[2];
float gyroscopeArrayT[3];
float angleArrayT[3];

String resulSerialT;

long previousMillisT;

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(signalPathRT);
  Wire.write(0x6B);
  Wire.write(0);
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(signalPathRT);
  Wire.write(0x3B);
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(signalPathRT, 6, true);
  acXT = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  acYT = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  acZT = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();

  accelerationArrayT[1] = atan(-1 * (acXT / accelerationRT) / sqrt(pow((acYT / accelerationRT), 2) + pow((acZT / accelerationRT), 2))) * RAD_TO_DEG;
  accelerationArrayT[0] = atan((acYT / accelerationRT) / sqrt(pow((acXT / accelerationRT), 2) + pow((acZT / accelerationRT), 2))) * RAD_TO_DEG;

  Wire.beginTransmission(signalPathRT);
  Wire.write(0x43);
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(signalPathRT, 6, true);
  gyXT = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  gyYT = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();
  gyZT = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read();

  gyroscopeArrayT[0] = gyXT / turnRT;
  gyroscopeArrayT[1] = gyYT / turnRT;

  differentialT = (millis() - previousMillisT) / 1000.0;
  previousMillisT = millis();

  angleArrayT[0] = 0.98 * (angleArrayT[0] + gyroscopeArrayT[0] * differentialT) + 0.02 * accelerationArrayT[0];
  angleArrayT[1] = 0.98 * (angleArrayT[1] + gyroscopeArrayT[1] * differentialT) + 0.02 * accelerationArrayT[1];

  resulSerialT = "Grados de inclinacion en X: " + String(angleArrayT[0]) + " | " + "Grados de inclinacion en Y" + String(angleArrayT[1]);
  Serial.println(resulSerialT);
  delay(100);
}
```